# Set all UILabels to subclass programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, subclassing

I have many many many existing `UILabels` in a project that I want to subclass.  Rather than spending days going through them all individually in IB setting them to my `UILabel` subclass want to set them programmatically

Checked here:
[How to programmatically set custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051353/how-to-programmatically-set-custom-class)

Couple of guesses tried:  `UILabel_setClass(self.contentView, [MyLabel class]);` -  implicit declaration error

and:

```
        Class  lbl = [[MyLabel alloc] init];

        for (id view in [self.contentView subviews]) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

                 //....sub it here?

                 }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it's very bad idea to change object class. It's one of kind of *smell code*. If in the future a new developer will use default `UILabel` class it can get strange errors.  Runtime - is a great and worst feature of objective-C. It can create hidden bugs in bad hands. So use it very carefully and twice think - do you really need it in the project. And better - write your code explicit, use design patters etc.

In your question is not clear why do you need to change the object class. If you need it to change appearance - then use `UIAppearance`. If you need extend functionality, use `Extensions`.

Comment: its a unique circumstance and UIAppearance will not work due a problem when printed as PDF.  Design patterns etc are fine when not working on existing project in real world scenario